# Why does my newly created Heroku app not open?

Tags: web, heroku, deployment, web-applications

My newly created heroku app doesn't open, I got a [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6ei.png)  that says "**Heroku | Welcome to your new app!**
Refer to the *documentation* if you need help deploying" Since it's not showing any error message I'm unable to diagnose it. Also there was a exactly same question here but it is no more.

Comment: What are your environment and the output of the build log?

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it by myself that, my app was not recognized as a python app so I added requirements.txt, runtime.txt and procfile. Then I choosed a different runtime because my python version was not compatible w/ heroku-20. And it worked for me.